# OpenStreetMap Stata Geocoding (JSON)

Tags: python, json, stata, openstreetmap, geocoding

I am not too familiar with Stata's json capabilities.

Would it be possible to rewrite this python script in Stata?

```
import url
import requests

data = data[['Locality']]

def geocode2(locality):
    url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/' + urllib.parse.quote(locality) +'?format=json'
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    if(len(response)!=0):
        return(response[0]['lat'], response[0]['lon'])
    else:
        return('-1')

data['geocoded'] = data['Locality'].apply(geocode2)
```

I am looking to Geocode using the Open Street API as described here: https://www.natasshaselvaraj.com/a-step-by-step-guide-on-geocoding-in-python/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: I was not asking for someone to write the code for me. Just for some advice on how to get started. But I think I've figure it our.

Comment: Good questions here show some attempt at code.  That’s standard advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think got this running. Pre-link should just be whatever address you are trying to  geocode with commas (and other symbols) changed to their ASCII Code, and spaces replaced with "+".

```
ssc install insheetjson, replace
ssc install libjson, replace

local address = "..."
local pre_link = urlencode(address, useplus)
local jlink = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q="+"`pre_link'"+"&format=jsonv2"

insheetjson id name lat lon using "`jlink'", /*table(results)*/ col("place_id" "display_name" "lat" "lon") limit(1) replace
```

Now I am working on finding a way to iterate over all of my addresses without having to continuously reopen the data where the list of addresses lives.